# my pre_save signal is not working as i want to update my slug field using this signal

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-signals, django-3.0

here i want to create slug based on the content automatically just before the Question model instance is saved but the slug field is not created as i want to
here is my models.py

```
class Question(models.Model):
     created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
     updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
     content = models.CharField(max_length=240)
     slug = models.SlugField(max_length=240, unique=True) 
     author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                                   on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                   related_name="questions") 
class Answer(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    body = models.TextField()
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question,
                                 on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                 related_name="answers") 
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                               on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    voters = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                                    related_name="votes")
```

my apps.py

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class QuestionsConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'questions'

    def ready(self):
        import questions.signals
```

my **init**.py

```
default_app_config = "questions.apps.QuestionsConfig"
```

and finally the signals.py

```
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.utils.text import slugify   #we'll use it to create slug based on the content of the instance

from core.utils import generate_random_string
from questions.models import Question

@receiver(pre_save, sender=Question)
def add_slug_to_question(sender,instance,**kwargs):
    if instance and not instance.slug:
        slug = slugify(instance.content)
        random_string = generate_random_string()
        instance.slug = slug + "-" + random_string
```

Comment: Hi, did you find any answer or solution. I have the same problem